# Get all validation errors from Angular 2+ FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-forms

```
public static getFormErrors(formGroup: FormGroup, server_errors = {}): any {
    let errors = {};

    Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(key => {
        const controlErrors: ValidationErrors = formGroup.get(key).errors;

        if (controlErrors != null) {
            Object.keys(controlErrors).forEach(keyError => {
                errors[key] = SharedModule.readableError(key, keyError, controlErrors[keyError]);
            });
        }
    });

    if (server_errors) {
        Object.keys(server_errors).forEach(key => {
            errors[key] = SharedModule.readableError(key, server_errors[key][0], '');
        });
    }

    return errors;
}
```

How can I get all validation errors (including both FormArray and FormGroup) from this.form?

P.S. The current code above outputs

```
{name: "Name is required", email: "Email is required"}
```

and I want the nested output as

```
{name: "Name is required", email: "Email is required", "myFormGroup": [{"myControl1": "myControl1 is required"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe little late or you found this out already but I came across the same. What I did is loop through the array and find if it's valid. If it's not valid get the variable and put it in the error.

Here my solution:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.form.controls['array']['controls'].length; i++){
    if (!this.form.controls['array']['controls'][i]['valid']) {
       let field = this.form.controls['array']['controls'][i]['controls']['fieldname']['value']; // fieldname is the value of your control
       errors[field] = `${field} is required`;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I managed to do it like this - https://gist.github.com/surferxo3/dfde629413561d988fb89efb700d6ddf